# how to make this line execute only once and later it should not be called or executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
          element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
        },
```

in the above function, how can i make this function run only once,
this funtion

> ```
>       element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
> ```

it should disappear as soon as i execute that line, and let me tell you it will be executed when i drag and drop elements and this is fine to me, but some times when i try to sort that event it gets execute and 'x' alpha falls next to event name.
[complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/166uz7L1/9/)

Comment: Checkout jQuery.one() function. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AsifAadeez/166uz7L1/11/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this somewhere in your code:

```
$(element).on("eventRender", this.eventRender);
```

You can do this

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
  element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
  element.off("eventRender");
},
```

If `eventRender` is only the handler name and not a custom event name, just replace it with the event type, i.e. click or keyup

**EDIT**

Also, jQuery supplies an event binding method `.one()` that automatically removes the eventListener after it has been called once. To use simply replace your `.on("eventRender")` code with `.one("eventRender")`

Comment: `one()` instead of `on()` would do this automatically.

Comment: @AndrewR Thats true, but I thought this is probably easier to convey considering that we don't have the event binding code. I'll append it to my answer for clarity though.

Comment: I just dug into the complete code (I didn't see that link at the bottom of the question until just now.) It looks like this is a function that is passed into a jQuery plugin. In that case, @Milan Chheda's answer is probably the best option.

Comment: this one is working in fiddle but not in normal html page

Answer (score 0):

Just do a check whether the span exists or not:

```
if(element.find("span.close").length) { 
     // span has already been appended, do something else here.. 
 } else {
    element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
 }
```